# Syntax Error when Appending item to List in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

Here's my full code:

```
let xyz m l =
    let r1 l m = if ((m mod 2) = 0) then l:=1::!l; !l else !l in r1 l m


let l = ref []
let y = xyz 250 l

let () = List.iter (fun x -> print_int x) y
```

it is returning the following error:

```
ocamlopt loops.ml -o l
File "loops.ml", line 21, characters 54-58:
21 |     let r1 l m = if ((m mod 2) = 0) then l:=1::!l; !l else !l in r1 l m
                                                           ^^^^
Error: Syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
l := 1 :: !l; !l
```

is two expressions separated by `;`. However, only a single expression can appear after `then`. Since you have two expressions, by the time the `else` shows up it is no longer permitted syntactically.

Another way of looking at it is that `if-then` and `else` have higher precedence than `;`.

You can make two expressions into one by parenthesizing them:

```
if ... then ( l := 1 :: !l; !l ) else ...
```

There may be other problems in your code but this is the reason you have a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to use refs, since you're creating a new binding for your new list. And for functional programming languages like OCaml would be better avoiding them any way.

```ml
let xyz m l =
    let r1 l m = if ((m mod 2) = 0) then 1 :: l else l in
        r1 l m

let l = []
let y = xyz 250 l

let () = List.iter (fun x -> print_int x) y
```

Your code now looks much more simpler and you don't even need the extra internal closure and the anonymous function:

```ml
let xyz m l =
    if ((m mod 2) = 0) then 1 :: l else l

let l = []
let y = xyz 250 l

let () = List.iter print_int y
```